# UE5 LyraStarterGame How to ULyraWeaponStateComponent is added in Controller?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I’m analyzing LyraGameplayAbility_RangedWeapon to study LyraStarterGame’s weapon attack capabilities. I confirmed that the server-client prediction function for weapon attacks is in the ULyraWeaponStateComponent, but I couldn’t figure out how to add this component to the controller. There was no component creation part in the C++ code, and this component is not even used in the blueprint. However, when I used the FindComponentsByClass node to check for the presence of ULyraWeaponStateComponent, it was always present in the controller. This component is not used or created in C++ code or blueprints, but I am curious about how the component is added to the controller.